# In Excel, how can I get a dynamic list of the distinct values from the same column in 3 tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have 3 tables in the same Excel workbook, all of which use the same column headers.

I want to have a column in a 4th table that can *dynamically* update with all the distinct values that are found in the same column across all 3 tables (e.g. Table01[MyCol], Table02[MyCol], Table03[MyCol]).

A VBA solution is fine; I just don't know where to begin.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the new `FILTER()` and `UNIQUE()` functions ??

Answer (score 0):

> *A VBA solution is fine; I just don't know where to begin.*

If you want something *'that can dynamically update'*, you are probably seeking a solution based on an 'event'. There are events triggered by updates from other sources to tables as well as any change to any worksheet.

If your tables are all on the same worksheet, you should be able to get away with a worksheet event trigger; if they are on different worksheets then you need a workbook event trigger.

Every time I hear the terms *'distinct values'* and *'VBA'* in the same paragraph, I immediately start thinking about a VBA Scripting Dictionary. The dictionary's *keys* are unique (optionally either case sensitive or not).

Since the column in question is *'the same column across all 3 tables'*, you should probably use a public or private constant variable to determine its name. If the columns' name was ever to change, you only need to change it in one place.

Dealing with structured tables in VBA can be a pain. Different methods have different pros and cons. I've found the method with the least number of cons to be `Range("Table01").ListObject` as a ListObject table, particularly so when dealing with a workbook's tables and not just a single worksheet's tables.

Don't loop through each table's column cell-by-cell. Read each table's column into a variant array and loop through the array. It's faster and less calculation intensive.

Here is some code that derives a unique list of values from three tables on two worksheets into a fourth table on a third worksheet. It belongs in the **ThisWorkbook** code sheet. Heavily commented for your benefit.

```
Option Explicit

'declare the common column's name available to all sub procedures within this code sheet
Private Const col As String = "col2"

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    'the Intersect function sees if you have changed anything within the tables
    'you cannot Intersect across worksheets so you need to know what worksheet contains which table
    'in this case, Table01 and Table02 are on Sheet1, Table03 is on Sheet2
    'note the use of the LCase function
    Select Case LCase(Sh.Name)
        Case "sheet1"
            'did the change event (add/update/remove) occur on Sheet1.Table01 or Sheet1.Table02
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Table01").ListObject.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange, _
                                     Range("Table02").ListObject.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
                'set error control
                On Error GoTo byebye
                'disable events so this doesn't run on top of itself when Table04 is updated
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                'run the Table04 update procedure
                UpDate_Table04
            End If
        Case "sheet2"
            'did the change event (add/update/remove) occur on Sheet2.Table03
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Table03").ListObject.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
                'see above
                On Error GoTo byebye
                'see above
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                'see above
                UpDate_Table04
            End If
        Case Else
            'do nothing (placeholder for other considerations)
    End Select

'error control 'catcher'
byebye:
    'reenable event handling for future operations
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub UpDate_Table04()

    'declare variables
    Dim t As Long, v As Long, tbls As Variant, vals As Variant
    'declare a reusable variable for the dictionary
    Static d As Object

    'assign the source table names to a variant array
    tbls = Array("Table01", "Table02", "Table03")

    'determine if the dictionary has been created
    'if so remove all previous entries; if not create one and make it non-case-sensitive
    If d Is Nothing Then
        'dictionary does not exist; create one and make it non-case-sensitive
        Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        d.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Else
        'dictionary exists; remove all previous entries
        d.RemoveAll
    End If

    'loop through the three source tables
    For t = LBound(tbls) To UBound(tbls)

        'retrieve the values from this table's common column
        vals = Application.Transpose(Range(tbls(t)).ListObject.ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange.Value2)

        'loop through the values and create create unique dictionary keys using the faster Add/Overwrite method
        'this method does not require checking for identical previous additions
        For v = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
            'Add/Overwrite method
            d(vals(v)) = vbNullString
        Next v

    Next t

    'work with the destination table
    'this reference method does not require worksheet reference within ThisWorkbook
    With Range("Table04").ListObject
        'make room/remove rows on the destination table
        .Resize .HeaderRowRange.Cells(1).Resize(d.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count)
        'put the dictionary keys into the destination table
        .ListColumns(col).DataBodyRange = Application.Transpose(d.keys)
    End With


End Sub
```

I'm willing to answer any questions that you have already been researched and cannot find an answer to.

Answer (score 0):

*Rather than VBA code I would like to suggest an Array(CSE) formula, will create unique list in another column.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Create three Table and name them as `NameTBL`, `NameTBL1` &  `NameTBL2`.
- Formula in cell `J36`:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(IFERROR (IFERROR(INDEX(NameTBL[City1],MATCH(0, COUNTIF($J$35:J35, NameTBL[City1])+(NameTBL[City1]=""), 0)), INDEX(NameTBL1[City2], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($J$35:J35, NameTBL1[City2])+(NameTBL1[City2]=""), 0))), INDEX(NameTBL2[City3], MATCH(0, COUNTIF($J$35:J35, NameTBL2[City3])+(NameTBL2[City3]=""), 0))), "")}
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill it down (till few extra rows).

---

- *New Data has been added to Table 1*

[image]

---

- *New Data added in Table 3.*

[image]

**N.B.**

- *Since Excel automatically updates related tables as soon gets new data, therefore the formula in `Column J` dynamically includes new value.*
- *You may convert unique value in `column J` into a Table.*

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point I found is at https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/, which includes variations for being case-sensitive, and ignoring numbers and blanks.

Rather than VBA or an Array/CSE formula, I'd prefer using this regular formula. Note it contains a relative reference to the cell directly above, e.g. the formula in cell D5 refers to the range from TableHeader to D4, rather than D1 as shown below.

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( Table1[MyCol], MATCH(0, INDEX( COUNTIF(TableDistinct[[#Headers],[DistinctVals]]:D1,Table1[MyCol]),0,0),0)),
                 IFERROR( INDEX( Table2[MyCol], MATCH(0, INDEX( COUNTIF(TableDistinct[[#Headers],[DistinctVals]]:D1,Table2[MyCol]),0,0),0)),
                          IFERROR( INDEX( Table3[MyCol], MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF(TableDistinct[[#Headers],[DistinctVals]]:D1,Table3[MyCol]),0,0),0)),
                                   "")
                 )
)
```

[image: Non-CSE and non-VBA formula returning distinct values from three tables]

This formula first uses `COUNTIF` to convert the list of source values {A,B,B,C} to a list of 1's and 0's based on the values already found in the distinct list. If the "A" and "B" values are already in the distinct list but "C" is not, then in this example it would convert {A,B,B,C} to {1,1,1,0}

Second, it uses `MATCH` on the binary array to find the first "0" value, which is the position of a source list cell with a value not yet contained in the distinct list. I.e. position 4 for the "C" value above.

Third, it uses `INDEX` to get the value associated with position found by `MATCH`, in our example it returns "C".

Last, it uses `IFERROR` to return `"""` (a blank cell value) when no more matches have been found.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel has the Dynamic Arrays feature, with the `UNIQUE` function, you can use:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Table01[MyCol],Table02[MyCol],Table03[MyCol]),",","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s"))
```

#### Algorhythm

- Join all the text together using `TEXTJOIN` function to create a comma-separated list *(or use some other delimiter if commas are included in your strings)*

  ```
   TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Table01[MyCol],Table02[MyCol],Table03[MyCol])`
  ```
- Create an XML with each node being one of the comma-separated items
- Use `FILTERXML` to return the nodes as an array.
- Use the `UNIQUE` function to return only the unique entries.

[image]